# How to validate a POST request for postUserAction

Tags: validation, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

I get a problem with the validation of a new user request on my api.
I know there's a problem in my code but I cannot figure it out :

[UserType](http://pastebin.com/3R74ehiU)

[postUserAction](http://pastebin.com/3uN7sVar)

And I send via google Postman, this json :

```
{
  "username":"Username",
  "email":"example@mail.com",
  "plainPassword":"SecretPassword",
  "lastname":"Smith",
  "firstname":"John",
  "job_position":"CEO",
  "phone":"+666133742",
  "company_name":"Microtosh",
  "website":"www.omgthatsaflippingspider.com",
  "sector":"Food & Stuff",
  "address":"12 st Overkill",
  "city":"SinCity",
  "zip_code":"W4224",
  "country":"US",
  "billing_infos_same_as_company":true,
  "putf":"1",
  "das":"Manchester United"
}
```

Now I seems to validate but I get an error :

```
Column 'password' cannot be null
```

When I look up the $form -- before $userManager->updateUser($user) -- I get this :

```
plainPassword:
{
    -children:
    {
        -first:
        {
            -errors:
            [
                "fos_user.password.mismatch"
            ]
        }
        second: [ ]
    }
}
```

Now first, why does it validate since it didn't find a match between password and confirmation ?

And am I doing the right thing, with the creation of a new user ? I don't understand what I am missing.

Comment: It's unclear a bit. Did you in fact comment out `plainPassword` form field? And why would you set the form type to `repeated` if you are building an API?

Comment: Well no I commented it for a test, sorry about that.
And now that you mention it, I don't know why I put 'repeated' as I looked everywhere to assemble my code, trying to do the right one.
I'll try to put it without the repeated.

Comment: Yup, tested it aaaaaand it work perfectly.
Please make it an answer so I can validate the hell out of it.

I love you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the form type of password field to `password` instead of `repeated` and it should work ;)